# How to submit an angular form with selenium python after filling out

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<button ng-click="LoginForm.login($event)" id="login_btn" ng-disabled="LoginForm.isSubmitting" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-large btn-submit ModalLoginSignup-loginForm-submitBtn" fl-analytics="NormalLogin" i18n-id="3bbbad631029e3575da7a151bba4f37c" i18n-msg="Log In">
                    Log In
                </button>
```

this is what I am trying.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://xxxxxxxxx.com")
user = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
user.clear()
user.send_keys("xxxxxxxx")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("xxxxxxx")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
# password.send_keys(u'\ue007')
# driver.click()
# driver.implicitly_wait(30)
# driver.find_element_by_id("login_btn").send_keys(u'\ue007')
# driver.find_element_by_id('login_btn').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("")



driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='login_btn']").send_keys(u'\ue007')
# login_button.submit()
# driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ModalLoginSignup-loginForm-submitBtn").submit()
```

Comment: Is this not a clickable element? Are you successfully selecting but at present no response in relation to interacting with it?

Comment: Are you sure it's a form? it looks like login screen. Does it have `<form>` tag?

Comment: <form name="LoginForm.form" class="user-login-form fl-form large-form responsive-form ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-valid-email-username ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required">

Comment: yes this is form

Comment: is the login button clickable? If yes, the just click it `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='login_btn']").click()`

Comment: and this button within the form

Comment: i have tried xpath by .click() but it doesnot work

Comment: @QHarr  yes and it also submit manually with enter

Comment: @Guy login form yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared the desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to invoke `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn-submit.ModalLoginSignup-loginForm-submitBtn#login_btn"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-info btn-large btn-submit ModalLoginSignup-loginForm-submitBtn' and @id='login_btn']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait`

Comment: it worked. thank you but when I put CSS selector and XPATH together. it's funny. it's like double-click.